# How can I run some script on Firebase backend?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have some Firebase web project with google cloud functions and a database. I want to run some script on the backend to move some data in the databases. How can I execute this script on the backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to run a script on your workstation and instead run it on a server, you can use [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) in the [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com).  This is good for one-time scripts.

This feature is not available in the Firebase console, but since every Firebase project is also a Google Cloud project, you will have access to all the same resources.

Comment: this looks like what i need. i entered the shell, now just to find out how to execute my script, i dont see my code in this shell.

Comment: when Im in the shell I dont see my sourcefiles anywhere. I have node project and I would like to access it in the shell to run some script. I tried to upload just one file and run it with 'node myfile.js', it works but it fails becuase needs all the dependencies.

Comment: uh i finally realized that I can run the script on my local machine and it will work with production databases because locally i chose firebase use 'prodn-env'... and you started your answer with "If you dont want to run a script in your workstation..." but my mindset was locked on server and didnt realized script can run locally and work with remote data.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly run simple scripts on your local machine.  There are cases where you might also want to run it on a google server, especially if it's going to transfer a lot of data, and you need that transfer to be as fast as possible.